# Unexpected line break before makebox with expl3 syntax

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, expl3

I want to type some texts as the following.

```
some text:____underline_text_______
```

I hope the total length of the above texts could be some given length. The length of the underline part depends on the previous normal texts.
I try to use the syntax of `expl3` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__fillitem:nnn
{
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box{#2}
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {#1 - \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}
  \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  \underline{\makebox[\dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim]{#3}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\fillitem{mmm}{\__fillitem:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\parindent0pt
text\rule{100pt}{1pt}\par
text\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}\par
\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}\\
\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}\\
\rule{100pt}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like the picture.

[image]

There will be an unexpected line break before the `\underline` command, if `\fillitem` appears in the beginning of a paragraph.

Otherwise, if there are some previous texts before the whole command `\fillitem`, the line break disappears, even if it is at the beginning of a line after `\\`.

This is strange. Could someone give some explanation?
Thank you very much!

In addition, if replace `\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box` with `#2` simply, the problem disappears.

Comment: a \hbox doesn't switch to horizontal move automatically. Use `\mode_leave_vertical:` before using the box. And please follow the naming conventions of expl3, `\__fillitem:nnn` should contain a modul prefix, e.g. `\__jia_fillitem:nnn`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “TeXhackers” note behind `\box_use:n` says that this is the same as the primitive `\copy`. In particular, it doesn't start LR-mode (in plain TeX speak this is “horizontal mode”).

If you want the box to start horizontal mode you need the equivalent of `\leavevmode`, that is,

```
\mode_leave_vertical:
```

Fixed code. You should use `\cs_new_protected:Nn` because the function performs assignments and better naming conventions.

You don't need `\dim_use:n`, because the optional argument to `\makebox` accepts a length.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{expl3,xparse} % not necessary with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\fillitem{mmm}{\jia_fillitem:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jia_fillitem:nnn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#2}
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {#1 - \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}
  \mode_leave_vertical:
  \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  \underline{\makebox[\l_tmpa_dim]{#3}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

text\rule{100pt}{1pt}

text\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}

\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}\\
\fillitem{100pt}{a b c}{d e f}\\
\rule{100pt}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is more than my expectation! Thanks a lot!